# Karate Driver interaction with iframe

Tags: karate

Having difficulty with Karate Driver and inputing data into fields that are in an iframe

Have tried using xpath and css selectors to the iframe so I could theoretically switch into and interact with the iframe without any luck.   I can find the iframe but I am unsure how to switch context to the iframe so the scenario can continue inside the iframe.   For example inputting values into fields in the iframe.

Help Please :)

Update:
Can successfully switch into an iframe but now running into an issue with nested iframe.

```
* switchFrame(0)
* click('.some-checkbox')
* switchFrame(0)
```

neither iframe has great css selectors.   The second switchFrame with an index of 0 is not looking to the nested iframe.

Comment: in order to get a bit more help i think post some example code to show what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have seen the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#switchFrame

I admit this is very tricky. Ideally you have a proper CSS or ID selector to the frame and this is an actual working example from a test I have. Note that the `waitFor()` may be what you are missing, especially when the `<iframe>` is some slow loading bloatware.

```
* waitFor('.some-css-name iframe').switchFrame()
* click('.some-checkbox')
* switchFrame(null)
```

And unfortunately I have found that this tends to work best on driver type: `chrome` and `chromedriver`

Comment: That works!   Bad part is that we have nested iframes.  I can switch into 1 and input stuff but then can't switch into the next one.   Thoughts?   I know crazy (an iframe within an iframe)

Comment: @coolBeans wow. would be great if you can contribute some fixes :|